# C++ - Breaking code implementation into different parts

Tags: c++

The question plot (a bit abstract, but answering this question will help me in my real app):

So, I have some abstract superclass for objects that can be rendered on the screen. Let's call it `IRenderable`.

```
struct IRenderable {
  // (...)
  virtual void Render(RenderingInterface& ri) = 0;
  virtual ~IRenderable() { }
};
```

And suppose I also have some other objects that derive from `IRenderable`, e.g. `Cat` and `Dog`.

So far so good. I add some `Cat` and `Dog` specific methods, like `SeekForWhiskas(...)` and `Bark(...)`. After that I add specific `Render(...)` method for them, so my code looks this way:

```
class Cat : public IRenderable {
public:
  void SeekForWhiskas(...) {
    // Implementation could be here or moved
    // to a source file (depends on me wanting
    // to inline it or not)
  }

  virtual void Render(...) {
    // Here comes the rendering routine, that
    // is specific for cats
    SomehowDrawAppropriateCat(...);
  }
};

class Dog : public IRenderable {
public:
  void Bark(...) {
    // Same as for 'SeekForWhiskas(...)'
  }

  virtual void Render(...) {
    // Here comes the rendering routine, that
    // is specific for dogs
    DrawMadDog(...);
  }
};
```

And then somewhere else I can do drawing the way that an appropriate rendering routine is called:

```
IRenderable* dog = new Dog();
dog->Render(...);
```

***My question is about logical wrapping of such kind of code.***

*I want to break apart the code, that corresponds to rendering of the current object and it's own methods (`Render` and `Bark` in this example), so that my class implementation doesn't turn into a mess (imagine that I have 10 methods like `Bark` and of course my `Render` method doesn't fit in their company and would be hard to find).*

Two ways of making what I want to (as far as I know) are:

- Making appropriate routines that look like `RenderCat(Cat& cat, RenderInterface* ri)`, joining them to `render` namespace and then the functions inside a class would look like
  `virtual void Render(...) { RenderCat(*this, ...); }`, but this is plain stupid, because I'll lose access to `Cat`'s private members and friending these functions looks like a total design disaster.
- Using visitor pattern, but this would also mean I have to rebuild my app's design and looks like an inadequate way to make my code complicated from the very beginning.

*Any brilliant ideas? :)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding and recollection from when I dinked with graphic programming is the Visitor is indeed appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd say to just sort the functions in your files intelligently and that will mostly cover it, but that doesn't sound that that's quite what you're looking for.

You could always put the display-related stuff in one class and the non-display stuff in another and use multiple inheritance. Separating GUI stuff from the logic is quite typical thanks to the MVC design pattern. It's often a great way of doing things, but I don't know how well it applies to what you're doing.

Another possibility would be to just put the the function definitions in separate files. There's nothing requiring you to put all of the function definitions for a class all in one file. Instead of Dog.cpp, you could have Dog.cpp which includes Dog_DisplayFunctions.cpp and Dog_ActionFunctions.cpp or something like that.

Comment: You ALWAYS want to separate business logic from view no matter what patters or architecture you use to do that.  Doing otherwise makes your business logic very difficult to reuse and makes adding or changing views likewise ungainly.

Comment: Oh, I agree with that. But if you're doing something really simple for the "view" portion, it might not be worth separating it from the logic. If you're doing anything with any real size to it though, there's pretty much no question that separating the logic from the view is going to a good idea.